# Drawing A Big Image in View

Tags: ios, image, drawing

I want to draw an image with size bigger than the frame of a view, and keep the origin image size and quality.

I try draw with the view frame, but it loses quality.

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageViewDrawing.frame.size);
   [self.imageViewDrawing.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageViewDrawing.frame.size.width, self.imageViewDrawing.frame.size.height)];
```

SS: http://www.imagebam.com/image/215dd5285081681

I try draw with the size of image, but it just draw in the image draw context frame size.

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageViewDrawing.image.size);
   [self.imageViewDrawing.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageViewDrawing.image.size.width, self.imageViewDrawing.image.size.height)];
```

SS: http://www.imagebam.com/image/682962285081678

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageViewDrawing.frame.size);
   [self.imageViewDrawing.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageViewDrawing.image.size.width, self.imageViewDrawing.image.size.height)];
```

SS: http://www.imagebam.com/image/f80341285082782

Answer (score 0):

A good solution could be to use the `UIIMage+Resize` Category presented here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

It works well and keep quality of images